# connect eclipse web application to sql 2012 database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I'm looking into how to connect a web application to an sql 2012 database "MyTestDatabase" with Windows authentication. I have a similar project that is a simple java application that prints out the contents of a table. here's the code for it...

```
public class sqldriver {
Connection connection = null;
public sqldriver() {}
public boolean doConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=MyTestDB;integratedSecurity=true"); 
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException : " + e.getMessage()); return false;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

All I can find are tutorials for Derby and that's not what I need. The error I keep getting is...

> WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

I've added the sqljdbc_auth.dll to the web-inf/lib, but it doesn't fix the problem. Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you add your database in the odbc !!
Go to the start menu and type Odbc then it will appear a dialog >>
select the system dsn tap then select add then select your server whatever Mysql Or ms Access
after that enter your DB info if you select Mysql then save by click ok
then go to your Code and make a string whith your config and send it to the connection object!!

note:
You should delete your constructor and leave the compiler run the default..

Comment: It didn't help me connect but you did teach me something I didn't already know. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

To load sqljdbc_auth.dll, you either need to include the DLL in a location on the system PATH, or you need to explicitly specify the java.library.path property in the run configuration of Eclipse.

Comment: I tried specifying the java.library.path in the run configuration. It doesn't work whether I put in the Program arguments: space or the VM arguments: space